# Imported Roblox obj Model looks weird

Tags: modeling, import, obj

I tried to import my Roblox character as an .obj. But after I imported it, it totally looks messed up (like holes in it). Usually it worked a while ago! I hope you can help me!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to dissable show backface or just set the blend mode to opaque [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing it from Roblox, if it was working before the problem might have been the file getting corrupted